# css vh and vw, why doesnt vw value change when shifting orientation?

Tags: html, css

This was a hard question for me to google, I only found general descriptions which didnt explain my problem. I have a simple page with css to size a box: `width=10vw and height=10vh`.

On the page I use javascript and getComputedStyle() to show the actual pixels of the box (div). When viewing on my mobile, it will say `102x154` (height x width) in portrait and `54x154` (height x width) in landscape.

This seems strange to me. Why doesnt vw shift? Shouldnt both vh and vw trade places, so to speak?

EDIT: I now how some code to show:

```
    <style>
body{
    font-size:8vw;
}
#box
{
    width:15vw;
    height:15vh;
    background-color:silver;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="box">Test</div>

    <script>
        window.onresize =resize;
        resize();
        function resize()
        {
            var el = document.getElementById("box");
            var st = window.getComputedStyle(el);
            el.innerText = st.height + " x " + st.width;
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

I have tested this with Google Chrome device emulator switching devices and orientation. I have verified the resolution changes according to orientation. Still, the st.width never changes. The st.height changes as expected.

I hope I am missing some obvious "gotchas" here.

Best regards,
Rune

Comment: Maybe some content expands your height no matter what you set?

Comment: are you sure that when you inspect element in mobile and change from potrait to landscape, the screen resolution are A x B and the B x A ? maybe that's the problem. they should trade places. or try to set `max-height` and `max-width` also so the content of the box doesn't increase the height or width

Comment: It changes for me in this pen https://codepen.io/adogandesign/full/WRZmNv/
I'm using Google Chrome device emulator as well

Comment: Did you change the code somehow? Because for me it does not work. I testet physical windows phone, physical android (one of the new ones, cant remember) and also device emulating in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I did infact overlook something. When adding a meta tag for viewport and setting a initial scale, it works.

Thanks for all comments!

Cheers,
Rune